# Get next buffer in emacs, but not switch to it

Tags: emacs

Can emacs return the next buffer but not switch to it like

```
(next-buffer)
```

-------EDIT------

What I want is to **display the buffer name before run (switch-to-next-buffer)**, so I can know to which buffer it is going to switch.

I solve this problem as @lawlist suggested. But also need to comment out

```
(set-window-next-buffers)
```

which would modify the behavior of (switch-to-next-buffer)

Comment: Open up the function `switch-to-next-buffer` in the library `windows.el` and you will see that the last section of that function refers to a `new-buffer`.  That is what you need --- just create a new function and adjust it to your liking.  E.g., disable `set-window-buffer-start-and-point . . .` in that new function . . . .

Comment: Downgraded this from an answer because it doesn't return the same thing as `switch-to-next-buffer`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're after.  Anyway:  `(other-buffer)` returns the most recently selected buffer.  `(cl-find-if-not #'minibufferp (buffer-list) :start 1)` returns the next non-minibuffer buffer in the buffer list.  `switch-to-next-buffer`'s decision rule is much more complicated than that, however.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan says, it rather depends upon the logic that you're after for what "next" means.

`get-next-valid-buffer` may well be appropriate. e.g.:

```el
(let ((blist (buffer-list)))
  (while blist
    (let ((buf (get-next-valid-buffer blist (current-buffer) t)))
      (if buf
          (progn 
            (message "Next: %s" buf)
            (setq blist (delq buf blist)))
        (message "Undesirable: %s" blist)
        (setq blist nil)))))
```